# basic event listener for arrow keys

Tags: jquery, events

I have "back" and "next" links on each of my web pages, and I want to use the left and right arrow keys to trigger the links which go to the last or previous page. I'd really appreciate directions for the most basic code to do this (am very much a beginner) and where each piece of code goes. I already have a link to jquery. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 37) { // left     
      $(".previous a").trigger("click");
  }
  else if(e.which == 39) { // right     
      $(".next a").trigger("click");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="full-size-image-nav">
    <%if previousNumber <> 0 then%>
        <div class="previous">
            <p><a onclick="alert('Left arrow key');">Left</a></p>
        </div>
    <%end if%>
    <%if nextNumber <> 0 then%>
        <div class="next">
            <p><a onclick="alert('Right arrow key');">Right</a></p>
        </div>
    <%end if%>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. I know this is a totally amateurish question, but I put this in my basic test page between the body tags and see on the resulting web page:

Comment: <%if previousNumber <> 0 then%>
Left

<%end if%> <%if nextNumber <> 0 then%>
Right

<%end if%>